# Select a specific number of items of a specific type which are brothers with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I wish to add a class to pictures in a p only if they're strictly 2 pics in the p (not an alone img or more than 2), with a jQuery selector.

```
<div class="wysiwyg">
   <p>
      <img class="addHere"/>
      <img class="addHere"/>
   </p>
   <p>
     <img/>
   </p>
</div>
```

For now, I have something like this :

```
jQuery(".wysiwyg:has(p:nth-of-type(2)) img").addClass('MyClass');
```

The problem is that if there is only 1 img in a p, it's getting the class too. Have you an idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many ways. One could be to filter it:

```
jQuery(".wysiwyg p").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('img').length === 2;
}).find('img').addClass('MyClass');
```

Or:

```
jQuery(".wysiwyg p img").filter(function(){
    return $(this).siblings('img').length === 1;
}).addClass('MyClass');
```

Or use following selector (quite unreadable):

```
jQuery(".wysiwyg p:has(img:gt(0)):not(:has(img:gt(1))) img").addClass('MyClass');
```

Comment: I didn't know about filter ! It's a smart way to do it :) Thanks :)